# Is there a way to resize the live TV view on Google TV?

Tags: google-tv

I have searched around a lot and know that is not possible to overlay content on the live TV view on Google TV. What if I want to resize the live TV view and show my application content around the live TV view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a PIP API officially supported by Google TV. 
However, I managed to get the PIP video working by using android.widget.VideoView and using 'hdmi://localhost?port=2' as the video URI. Take a look at this app that I have open-sourced which shows how you could technically get PIP to work on Google TV: 
https://github.com/entertailion/GoogleTV-PIP

Comment: Thank you for the references and information. I hope Google officially supports this functionality one day.